# how can i show all of my value from database in a dropdown

Tags: php, while-loop, dropdown

i want to show every value of one of my column in dropdown until it finished but it doesnt work

```
<div class="dropdown dropstart text-end">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs- 
toggle="dropdown">
category
</button>
<?php if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
};
$sql = " SELECT category_name FROM categories";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {while($row = 
 mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
   
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="http://localhost/class/first/categories/new_categories.php">adding new category</a></li>
<li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><?php echo $row['category_name'] ?></a></li>

<?php }} ?>
</ul>`
```

Comment: What does `mysqli_num_rows($result);` return? Did you check? Put a `var_dump` and check

Comment: When you post a question, "it doesn't work" doesn't give people much to work with. Showing the html that gets generated would be helpful. One thing I see is that you are creating a `<ul>` element for every row returned.